# Show/hide images in sequence on hover

Tags: jquery, delay

I'm trying to hide and show images one after the other in a sequence using jquery, the last image to show and stay showing should be .img2. The following code doesn't work, the delay's dont seem to work, it just hides them all at the same time and shows .img2.

JQUERY

```
 $(".start-page-img").hover(function() {
            $('.img5').delay(6000).hide()
                    $('.img4').delay(7000).show()
            $('.img4').delay(9000).hide()
                    $('.img3').show(10000).show()
            $('.img3').delay(12000).hide()
            $('.img2').delay(13000).show()  

        });
```

HTML

```
<div class="start-page-img">
                               <img src="img/img1.jpg" class="img1" />
                                <img src="img/img2.jpg" class="img2"  />
                                <img src="img/img3.jpg" class="img3" />
                                <img src="img/img4.jpg" class="img4"  />
                                <img src="img/img5.jpg" class="img5" />
                            </div>
```

CSS

```
.start-page-img{
    width:400px;
    float:left; 
    position:relative;
    cursor:pointer;

}

.start-page-img img{
    position:absolute;  
    top:0;
    left:0;
    display:block;
}

.start-page-img .img1,
.start-page-img .img2,
.start-page-img .img3,
.start-page-img .img4,
{
    display:none;   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I managed to create the effect you are going for by using `setTimeout()` instead of `delay()`. Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CRnCS/3/) to play around. Notice, how some calls `show()` and `hide()` have a duration parameter, which in one case somehow overlaps the start of the next animation, so timing is everything.

There is probably a more elegant way, maybe with `jQuery.animate()` and/or `jQuery.queue()`.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure is this what you want:
[Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/3EJGG/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

//You can also do delay like this:
//$('.img3').delay(3000).fadeOut(5000);

//Or do hide like this:
//$('.img5').delay(1000).hide(5000,function(){
//$('.img4').delay(2000).hide(5000,function(){
//$('.img3').delay(3000).hide(5000);
//});
//});
//});


$('.hover_me').hover(function(){
$('.img5').fadeOut(5000,function(){
$('.img4').fadeOut(5000,function(){
$('.img3').fadeOut(5000);
});
});
});
});
```